# Wait for docker container restart in python

Tags: python, docker, testing, wait

I am in the process of programming some tests in Python. In one test, I am using a container that loads data from a database when the container starts.

In the test I modify the data in the database and restart the container with `os.system("docker-compose restart predict")` , so the latest data is loaded in the container.

Is there (besides the `wait-for-it.sh` repo) an option to wait with the execution until the container is up and running, directly in python?

Comment: If Docker weren't involved, how would you know that the other process was up and running?  (Just starting the process probably isn't enough, since you still need to wait for it to load its data and set up its network listener.)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`wait-for-it.sh` pools resources exposed from for the container and waits for the resource to became available (ip address, exposed port, or both).

#### Using docker-py

Following is a canonical approach with `python` and `docker-py` (docker's own python library) which will help you to orchestrate your containers even better.

First we import the packages that we need and crate a client to the docker engine

```
import docker
import os
import time

client = docker.from_env()
container="predict"
```

Next step is to restart the container by calling `restart`

```
client.restart(container)
```

or by cycling the `stop`, waiting for the stop and`start`

```
client.stop(container)
client.wait(container)
client.start(container)
```

#### Container lifecycle vs entry point process lifecycle

You also need to make distinction between **waiting for the container to restart** and **waiting for the entry process to restart**.

From the perspective of the docker engine, the moment when the entry process will start, the container is started. However, the process (like in your case) might need to do some preparation work before it's ready to start working. In such case, you need to create a mechanism for your python script to understan that the process in the container is ready. A simple creation of a file when the process is ready (after reading the cache) will be sufficient. The file can be created in a mounted filesystem, so you can use the `os.path.exists()` to check if the file is created.